# Is there a graphic web browser that can used inside of emacs?

Tags: emacs, browser

I remember seeing something of that sort a couple of years ago but I can't recall what it was? I'm not searching for conqueror which is an external web browser.

Does any of you about such a browser?

Comment: Though it's not yet stable, I keep an eye on [emacs-xwidgets](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXWidgets)

Comment: As of Emacs 24.4 (not yet released), there is a built-in web browser: `M-x eww` (alias `M-x web`). That's an enhancement of the `shr` html rendering that's been in since 24.1, so you can make do with that in some situations; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632185/display-contents-of-remote-html-in-emacs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

w3m can be run in Emacs buffer as well through [emacs-w3m](http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/). Note that contrary to Emacs/W3, this is not a pure browser implemementation in Emacs Lisp, but an interface to a standalone tool, and in fact it's not graphical as well.

Some day http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXWidgets work will be finished and hackers will be able to surf the interwebs conviniently without leaving Emacs at all since modern browsers will merge with their notorious ancestor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's being actively developed, but you might try EZBL:

- github: https://github.com/haxney/ezbl
- emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ezbl

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for [Emacs/W3](http://www.gnu.org/software/w3/) but as it stated in the [corresponding wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs/W3), it is now somewhat obsolete. A rewrite is pending, but I don't know about its status.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest EXWM - Emacs window manager. You can use any web browser you prefer with it. It works on linux only. You can use it alongside current DE or as a separate DE (in which case you may be interested in making sort of menu bars etc - just google how). Personaly I prefer Manjaro-KDE setup with EXWM running alongside KDE. You can read HN (Hacker News), reddit (r/emacs) for more detailed explanations and ideas. E.g. people can use firefox, chrome, nyxt (next), qutebrowser, eaf-browser in exwm with no problem. If you want to go deeper and integrate your gui browser with emacs [like here](https://github.com/atlas-engineer/nyxt/issues/195) you may consider nyxt, eaf-browser (readily integrated history), xwidget-webkit.
Firefox with KDE-browser integration and other hacks is also possible (see [ryan rix workflow](https://doc.rix.si/))