# Is there a way to look at a rendered website from within emacs?

Tags: html, emacs

The documentation for a library I'm using comes as a bunch of html files mixied in with the source code. It would be nice not to have to switch programs when I want to look at the documentation.

Is there a way to view a rendered html file from within emacs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a graphic web browser that can used inside of emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785916/is-there-a-graphic-web-browser-that-can-used-inside-of-emacs)

Comment: As of Emacs 24.4 (not yet released), there is a built-in web browser: `M-x eww` (alias `M-x web`). That's an enhancement of the `shr` html rendering that's been in since 24.1, so you can make do with that in some situations; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632185/display-contents-of-remote-html-in-emacs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. [Several](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWebBrowser).

Man, I feel like this question should have been "what can't emacs do." and I'm a vi man even.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same question, and neither of the answers is specific. For *rendering*, use [shr.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HtmlRendering) (Simple HTML Renderer):

```
(load-library "shr.el")
(shr-render-buffer)
```

Comment: Requires emacs to have been built with `libxml2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using w3m web browser for emacs. But it is very slow redering is sychronous.