# Display contents of remote HTML in Emacs

Tags: html, emacs, w3m

I am aware about **w3m** integration with Emacs but I am exhausted to make it run on my W7/x64: there is a permanent segmentation fault of w3m binary here.

I wonder if there is an alternative way to display remote HTML in Emacs possibly preliminary filtered in the way it is done by *Readability/GetPocket* etc. services? I do not need a navigation there so cleared contents would be perfect.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

trunk / Emacs 24.4:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eww` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(URL)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Emacs 24.1 - 24.3:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `browse-url-emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(URL)` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `shr` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shr-render-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```el
(defun my-render-url (url)
  "Render URL as HTML."
  (interactive "sURL: ")
  (require 'shr)
  (let ((buf (save-window-excursion (browse-url-emacs url))))
    (shr-render-buffer buf)))
```

*Edit:* or this, which has absolutely no error handling, but is considerably faster (which I attribute to browse-url-emacs using url-retrieve-synchronously, where as this is asynchronous). Feel free to make improvements :)

```el
(defun my-render-url (url)
  "Render URL as HTML."
  (declare (obsolete eww "24.4"))
  (interactive "sURL: ")
  (require 'shr)
  (url-retrieve
   url
   (lambda (&optional status cbargs)
     (let ((markup (current-buffer)))
       (delete-region (point-min) (1+ url-http-end-of-headers))
       (shr-render-buffer markup)
       (kill-buffer markup)))))
```

Comment: I wish I knew before about :) Will try to backport it to 24.1, should be no problems. Thanks!

Comment: For the current code in trunk, see [eww.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/net/eww.el?h=trunk), [shr.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/net/shr.el?h=trunk), and [shr-color.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/net/shr-color.el?h=trunk) (although I'm not sure if that's all you need, or how practical backporting will be).

Comment: The approach you have described above works like a charm for my 24.1 installation. Seems ''eww.el'' should be enough to have this feature on my local installation; but currently it does not work through the proxy but that is an another story.